# info windows on google map not showing

Tags: reactjs, api, google-maps

I have followed some of the suggestions posted here, but can't seem to get InfoWindows to show on the map. but even the markers don't show up? But the api calls are returning the correct data..

Here is most of my code, minus the api call, which is not the cause of the issue. Any help would be great! Thanks in advance :)

```
        <Map
            google={this.props.google}
            zoom={5}
            style={style}
            gestureHandling={'cooperative'}
            initialCenter={{
            lat: -19.577286,
            lng: 147.406473
            }}
        >
            {this.state.data.map((result) => {
                let keys = Object.keys(result);
                return keys.map(data => {
                    return (
                        <>
                        <Marker 
                            name={result[data].item1}
                            title={result[data].item2}
                            onClick={ this.onMarkerClick }
                            position={{
                              lat: result[data].lat,
                              lng: result[data].long
                            }}
                            animation={this.props.google.maps.Animation.DROP}
                        />
                        <InfoWindow
                            marker = { this.state.activeMarker }
                            visible = { this.state.showingInfoWindow } >

                                <div>
                                    <h4>{ this.state.selectedPlace.title }</h4>
                                    <p>{ this.state.selectedPlace.name }</p>
                                </div>

                        </InfoWindow>
                    </>
                    );
                });
            })}
        </Map>
```